# unable to add value assigned to the radio button to the rails registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, rolify

I m trying to restrict the operations which has to be done by registered users..

Here, i gave a value 1 to super admin, 2 to admin , 3 to guest....and i can able to save those values into db..but,

devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
 <%= f.radio_button :usertype,  '1' %>
 <%= f.label :usertype, "Super Admin", :value =>"true" %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <%= f.radio_button :usertype, '2' %>
   <%= f.label :usertype, "Admin", :value =>"false" %>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <%= f.radio_button :usertype, '3' %>
  <%= f.label :usertype, "Guest", :value =>"false" %>
</div>
```

but, once i logged in as a super admin/ admin /guest....every user is able to see all the operations done ....
how to restrict this access..??

models/ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
     user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role?(:super_admin)
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role?(:admin)
      can :create, Project
      can :update, Project do |project|
        project.ongoing?
      end
      can :read, Project
    elsif user.role?(:guest)
      can :create, Project
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: quick remark: CanCan is dead. Last update in 2013, we are 2017... If you want to use CanCan approach, you should migrate to CanCanCan which is currently supported.

Comment: So, is there any other approach other than the cancancan gem...?

Comment: Gem to manage roles: cancancan, pundit and rolify

Comment: The gems which i am using are: